# Alternating diagram of knots

Tags: knot-theory

Is it true that every tame knot has at least an alternating diagram?

If yes, is it true that we can always obtain an alternating diagram by a finite number of Reidemeister moves from a diagram of a knot?

If yes, how can we do it?

I am reading GTM Introduction to Knot Theory and find they sort of assume this, which makes me think it should be evident but I cannot figure out.

Comment: Can you point to exactly where in the book it seems like this is assumed?  (Also, it goes through the theory of PL topology and diagrams rather quickly, with bits scattered throughout the book.  You might consider supplementing it with other books, Rolfsen's included.)

Comment: @KyleMiller Sure. It is at the Chapter VI (Presentation of the Knot Group) 1. (The over and under presentations) the 3rd sentence. "These divide K into two classes of closed, connected segmented arcs, the overpasses and the underpasses, which alternate around the knot...". Thank you for the advice, I will check it.

Comment: Ah, I thought you were talking about Lickorish's book, not Crowell and Fox (I'm not particularly familiar with this one).  The "alternating" here does not mean "alternating diagram."  The way we usually draw a knot diagram on paper is with a bunch of disjoint arcs with gaps for where it goes under.  Imagine the knot just goes under the plane of the paper.  Then there are the drawn arcs and the under arcs, and if you think of this classification of points on the knot itself, you've decomposed it into a sequence of arcs of alternating classifications.

Answer (score 3):

A knot is called *alternating* if it has an alternating knot diagram.  If there is a sequence of Reidemeister moves on a diagram for a knot that results in an alternating diagram, then the knot is an alternating knot.  Because Reidemeister moves are a complete set of moves, given a diagram for an alternating knot, there is some sequence of Reidemeister moves that will give an alternating diagram.

Alternating knots are fairly special.  If $K$ is a prime alternating knot that is not a torus knot, then $S^3-K$ can be given a complete hyperbolic metric of constant negative curvature.  Using the geometrization theorem, it follows that any non-trivial [satellite operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_knot) gives a non-alternating knot.

If the knot is prime and alternating, then every minimal-crossing-number diagram is an alternating diagram (see [Alternating and Non-Altenating Knot projections with same crossing number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2660326/alternating-and-non-altenating-knot-projections-with-same-crossing-number)).  It's not clear to me if there exists a bounded-time algorithm that can actually find such a sequence of Reidemeister moves, however!  (There is always exhaustively trying all sequences of Reidemeister moves, but this is *a priori* an unbounded-time algorithm.)

Answer (score 0):

The former is true and is essentially a "checkerboard colouring" argument -- colour all the regions black and white, no two of the same colour sharing a border ( (ab)use Jordan curve theorem if you want to prove this ). Then as you travel towards a crossing, if there's black on your right as you approach, go under; otherwise, over.

The second is false according to [mathworld, wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlternatingKnot.html); this is a proof by counterexample (note that because that particular knot is non-alternating, you cannot make an alternating knot diagram by using Reidemeister moves as the positions you can get with Reidemeister moves are precisely the projections of the knot that you can get).

Comment: Thanks. I don't get the checkerboard argument. Doesn't the over- or under- crossing depends actually on the original knot that lives in $\mathbb{R}^3$? What I understand from you is that, once we have a projection of the knot into the 2D plane, we are free to assign whether a crossing is over- or under-.

Comment: I am not sure if I misunderstand the concept of the diagrams of a knot. I feel like your second part answers my first question, i.e., there are some knots that don't have any alternating diagrams at all, which, as you tell me, are called non-alternating themselves.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by "the former". It is not true that every tame knot has an alternating diagram as the Wolfram MathWorld link shows (8_(19), 8_(20), and 8_(21)).

Comment: @ClémentDato Given a link shadow (a link projection), there is always a way to turn it into an alternating diagram of a knot. The checkerboard argument is explained in Kauffman's _Knots and Links_ (3rd ed.) pp. 40–42 https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Knots_and_Physics/msMVUefjjnoC?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover